# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

Tor.SE is going to need a few moderators. SE sites are mostly community moderated, but you still need a few people to help keep everything in line. I believe Runa proposed this site on Area 51 initially, so there's candidate one.

Anybody else? Please post your nominations are separate answers so that they can be voted on. Self-nominations are allowed and encouraged!

When nominating, link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta). Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

If the nomination was posted by a 3rd-party, the nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer to add that they accept the nomination and optionally write something about themselves.

For more information about the Stack Exchange moderation philosophy and the initial moderator selection process, see here:

- [A theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Moderator pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

Comment: How many votes does one require to become moderator? How many will become moderator after getting votes here?

Comment: @adrelanos 1. SE Team chooses moderators, 2. Three

Comment: @adrelanos Pro Tem Moderators are appointed by the SE team, not elected, although popular opinion does figure into the decision. The initial team is made up  of 3 people **usually** consisting at least one subject matter expert and one (SE) network expert (read  somewhere on MSO, cant find source now).

Comment: The Pro Tem Moderators have been selected. The announcement is [over here](http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/questions/131/moderator-pro-tem-announcement). A new thread shall be started for Community Elected Moderators as the time arises.

Answer (score 17):

I nominate [Roger Dingledine](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/55/roger-dingledine), one of the original developers of Tor who is now at the center of our community. I don't think he needs much further introduction.

Comment: Well, maybe. Shouldn't I spend my time developing Tor and trying to answer Tor questions here? It looks like having lots of reputation points lets me do many things anyway. I guess it will depend on how much we turn out to be in need of moderators -- please help us identify more good ones. :)

Comment: @RogerDingledine - the moderation workload on a new beta site is generally pretty low... generally, and at least at first, and if you'll already be spending a lot of time here, it may help to have someone as one of the three moderators who is active and passionate about Tor. Just something to think about. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Would it matter if @RogerDingledine wouldn't do much with its moderation rights, just occasionally using them? I don't think there should be a minimum workload one has to do to stay moderator. Roger not having moderation rights like an equally bad idea to me as Roger not having admin rights at trac.torproject.org, even though he is not the trac maintainer.

Answer (score 11):

I nominate myself ([profile](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/198/runa), [meta](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/198/runa), [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/88683/)). I have worked for and with The Tor Project since 2009, started the Tor help desk a few years ago, and proposed the Tor page on Area 51 a few months ago.

Comment: Thanks for proposing this SE.  For a moderator, however, I would like to see a little more participation on the site itself first, maybe.  Cheers :)

Comment: I have to disagree with weasel here. Runa has done a lot of behind-the-scenes work to make this Stack Exchange page a reality. The work she's done promoting this SE site to the public, as well as her previous work on user support and outreach make her a great candidate for a moderator role.

Comment: @mttpgn - The participation doesn't necessarily have to be answering or asking questions, but a moderator should be someone who flags posts, and be someone who jumps in with suggested edits and comments to help improve posts. Participation helps when it comes time for the Stack Exchange community team to select the 3 moderators. They'll want to know they're selecting someone who has already hit the ground running, so to speak. Runa, if there are areas where you've participated that we can't see, that are on this site, you might consider highlighting them. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 10):

I nominate Jens Kubieziel ([profile](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/88/jens-kubieziel), [meta](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88/jens-kubieziel)). He's most active on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/236/qbi).

---

Some additions by Jens:
I know the Tor Project since quite a long time and use it since almost ten years now. Once I translated the Tor webpage into german and also wrote a [book about the general topic](http://www.opensourcepress.de/de/produkte/Anonym-im-Netz/102/978-3-941841-67-3).

As you already found out I'm a SE user, in the past mostly at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) as I helped to create the site.

If you'd like to know more just ask and I try to answer your question. :-)

Comment: It would be great if Jens could comment here and confirm that he is OK with being nominated as a moderator.

Comment: @Runa Jens has [edited it](http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/revisions/55/2).

Answer (score 10):

I nominate [Peter Palfrader](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/58/weasel-peter-palfrader) 'though I don't know anything about his parents, but he exists [metaphysically](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/weasel-peter-palfrader) at least.

I nominate him, because he's knowledgeable and gave a bunch of answers already.

He has also been involved in the Tor Project for 10 years, [running a directory authority](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/847B1F850344D7876491A54892F904934E4EB85D), working on tor from time to time, maintaining the [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/tor), and [keeping the infrastructure running](https://help.torproject.org/tsa/).  Further information: [torproject people page](https://www.torproject.org/about/corepeople.html.en), [non-closed tickets assigned to him or cc-ing him](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/query?owner=~weasel&status=accepted&status=assigned&status=needs_information&status=needs_review&status=needs_revision&status=new&status=reopened&or&status=accepted&status=assigned&status=needs_information&status=needs_review&status=needs_revision&status=new&status=reopened&cc=~weasel&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=owner&col=type&col=priority&col=cc&order=priority).

Answer (score 6):

I nominate myself ([main profile](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/15/samuel-walker), [meta profile](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15/samuel-walker)).

I'm active on several other SE sites, and have a clear understanding of the ethos behind Stack Exchange. See my profile over on [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/830/samuel-walker) for my most active profile. My [Global SE](http://stackexchange.com/users/278463/samuel-walker) profile shows that I'm active on a broad range of StackExchange sites - although some I mostly lurk on.

In terms of Tor itself, I'm a big user of Tor, and run my own relay (although I don't wish to publicly disclose which relay). I actively post over on the subreddits /r/Tor and /r/onions. I also, once did [an AMA](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/la1tc/by_request_iama_person_who_frequents_onion_i2p/) around Tor, i2p and Freenet. It was a while ago, and my knowledge has increased quite a bit since then. I would also hope that my communication skills have improved. In addition I regularly post over on [HackerNews](https://news.ycombinator.com/threads?id=lambada) in threads about Tor. Finally I lurk in the tor-relays mailing list, and #tor over on IRC. I hope these things demonstrate that my interest in Tor is not fleeting, and I am involved for the long haul.

I have also [written](http://www.samuelwalker.me.uk/2013/06/why-i-run-a-tor-relay/) a couple of [blog posts](http://www.samuelwalker.me.uk/2013/08/tor-freedom-hosting-tormail-firefox-and-recent-events/) on my personal site about Tor. As I think my website shows I'm someone who values privacy, anonymity and freedom of speech. I don't want to turn this into a political piece though, so I'll say no more about my own personal values.

I believe I can bring value, in terms of both knowledge and guidance of how Stack Exchange functions, to this community as it goes through an Open Beta and hopefully onwards into a permanent site on the Stack Exchange network.

Mandatory disclaimer: Any views I've expressed here, or in linked webpages, are my own and not necessarily those of my employer. I speak for myself and myself only.

Answer (score 6):

I nominate myself ([profile](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/107/mrphs), [meta](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/107/mrphs), [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/89091/mrphs)). I've started working with Tor Project in 2009 and joined Tor support team in 2011.

Answer (score 6):

I nominate myself ([profile](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/91/phoul), [meta](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/91/phoul), [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/88761/)). I have worked on the Tor help desk since September 2012.

Answer (score 5):

I nomintate myself ([profile](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/5/sam-whited), [meta profile](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/sam-whited)).

I have been active on Tor.SE since day one, and made contributions to the Area 51 proposal as well. I am most active on [Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) and also occasionally answer questions on [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6906/sam-whited) and other SE sites. See my [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/141416/sam-whited) for more info.

I maintain a Tor relay ([austrina](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/CA54C9F2AA56FE26D7A16F2693F65385E85E2D75)) and occasionally spin up exit nodes or bridges when I notice the network health is degraded. Though I don't work with the Tor Project directly, I have done a great deal of outreach and education and am always willing to help new users come to grips with Tor and help them understand what it does and doesn't do for their privacy and anonymity.

If you'd like to get in touch with me you can find me on IRC as SamWhited (Freenode, OFTC, and Geekshed mostly), or get ahold of me via email or XMPP via the addresses on my [contact page](https://blog.samwhited.com/about/) (PGP and OTR fingerprints available there as well).

Comment: I support Sam, I really like is constructive way of explaining what clarification he wanted for one of my question.

Comment: @GuillaumeCoté Thanks; I appreciate it. Actually though, moderator pro temp's have already been chosen (and I'm already one). Thanks again though, and thanks for clarifying your quesiton for everybody; I hope you find an answer to your liking!

Answer (score 0):

I'll nominate myself ([profile](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/21/iceyec), [meta-profile](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21/iceyec)). I have been fairly active in this SE even though I'm pretty new to being a participant on SE. sites.

I have been active on Tor.SE since its first day with asking and answering questions.

I have been running a Tor hidden service for a couple of months now at a fairly high volume and have experience digging around in Tor's more advanced configurations.

Answer (score -2):

**Moderator should have community trust, be fair and responsible.**

I can nominate myself ([main profile](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/159/ty221), [meta profile](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/users/159/ty221) - I have not  a lot of reputation, but this Q&A runs only 9 days, I promise - it will be higher, surly !), because fulfill these criteria, - I am the most active on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1952862/ty221), my reputation on [Area 51 is 468](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/76120/ty221).

I know how do Stack Exchange sites work - I am active a least than 8 months, I raised above 130 helpful flags, I made about 250 revisions and reviewed 310 posts.

If I will become a moderator of this site I promise that I will be fair, good and very often available. My main goal is keep that site clean and make it more helpful for new visitors, regular users and professionals.

Very important is also help for newbies - I promise that I will answer every message sent to me (if it will be not a nonsense, of course ! :). Our Q&A should be friendly for users and of course useful - spam, off-topic question, etc. should be closed or removed.

Who will vote for me will not regret - I will be good moderator and I will fulfill  all my promises. For any questions please ask in the comments.

Thank you in advance for your votes!

More information about me, you can find here : http://stackexchange.com/users/2210999/ty221

Comment: Generally you need at least 300 reputation to self nominate; see here for more info: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/

Comment: @SamWhited Yeah, you're generally true - but remember that it isn't same on every SE pages. For example on SO you need 3,000 reputation to nominate yourself. A nd so in general that article, which you provided, tells about non-pro-tempore moderators - there are information about regular elections. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/ doesn't give any reservation about reputation for pro-tempore moderators. Thank for your post - I hope that I've answered your comment cleary. Regards

Comment: Good point, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SamWhited You're welcome :)

Comment: Reputation is arguably less important for beta moderators, as long as not everyone is a n00b and as long as those who are are willing to be very open minded. It can sometimes be good to have balance here.

Comment: Reputation gives us a _general_ sense that you have the domain knowledge required to judge the _quality_ of a post, and the site as a whole. I'd encourage questions here in comments rather than email, though, so the answers are available to all.