# How to deal with abusive questions/users or flooding or SPAM?

Tags: discussion

As you can see in the screen-shot below a user posted the same question again and again.

Those questions showed up on the front page of tor.stackexchange.com and did not go away until enough users down-voted them or flagged them. (This took far too long for my taste.)

How can we brush them under the rock faster?

The user did not even try to flood this Q&A... I imagine how nice it will be if someone of some dudes actually try this. This could use some rate-limiting, especially when some user has only questions/answers with negative score (or only negative votes) and a reputability of 1.

[image: The current incident]

Comment: Hate the SPAM, not the spammer! If you do something nice that would still be wonderful, bob.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that, we've been keeping a pretty close eye on him (a now known persistent troll), but most of us spent at least part of the last 24 hours in the air flying to NY for a summit.

Just keep flagging, he'll get tired of having all traces of him removed with just a few clicks *well* before we get tired of doing it. As others noted, pro-tem appointments are coming very soon.

Answer (score 5):

What every regular member of the community should do is to flag those posts as spam/offensive. Six of those flags will auto-delete the post.

A moderator can just destroy all those accounts, though that will not prevent the person from creating new accounts. There are some ways to make this harder, but they require the intervention of an SE employee. SE is also currently working on some automated mechanisms that should make it much harder to spam a site.

Comment: "Six of those flags will auto-delete the post" That's an interesting feature. (I assume that a moderator can undo this if someone would abuse this function.) Sure the mods can do lots of useful things. Glad to here that some automation is on the way.

Comment: One problem is that jerks use proxies, VPNs and Tor to evade IP bans. Using persistent cookies etc is one workaround, I gather. However, such tactics would be ironic on tor.se ;)

Answer (score 4):

Keep flagging. [Moderator appointments](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/who-should-the-moderators-be) will be over soon, and then this sort of thing will be taken care of quicker (hopefully).

In the mean time, voting to close / flagging will automatically close the question / delete the answer after a few users do so. You can review close votes, low quality posts, etc. on the [review page](https://tor.stackexchange.com/review).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to gather some more reputation to view the votes on the review page.

Comment: `*`Pro Tempore Moderators are *appointed*, not elected.

Comment: Indeed; fixed now.