# When will elections take place?

Tags: discussion, moderators

There is a questions about [potential medorators](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/88). It exists for some time now and as far as I saw it no new nominations were added. According to [a blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) the nomination lasts seven days. So from my understanding the next step are elections. Is there a fixed timetable when they start? Do we have to take action and if yes, what do we have to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elections only take place once a site graduates, a beta site has pro-tempore moderators that are appointed by SE. These appointments usually take place a week or two after the start of the public beta, so they should happen pretty soon.

Comment: This is correct. The selection process is underway.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, moderators pro tempore are appointed by SE, not elected.  We will hold our elections once we have matured and can graduate out of beta.

[Robert's blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) seems to support this understanding.