# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Mrphs]
[image: Sam Whited]
[image: Samuel Walker]

***Update 1/17/2014***

Unfortunately, mrphs wasn't able to continue as he planned after coming on board, Jens Kubieziel has graciously stepped up holding his previous nomination and has accepted our invitation to join the team!

[image: Jens Kubieziel]

Please extend the same warm welcome to Jens.

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

> Did I overlook anyone?

Yes, [Peter Palfrader](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/a/96). [1829](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/58/weasel-peter-palfrader) reputation. Joined a little bit later but then contributed [most](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/56447/) answers. All of them high quality.

Comment: I think the question was rhetorical, but that's awesome that a user can jump in later and hit the ground running. Many "regular users" will end up being critical to the success of this site by flagging, voting to close/reopen, providing good leadership and asking/answering questions. :)